# EventStore persistent subscriptions not available in three node cluster after two nodes fail

Tags: c#, cluster-computing, eventstoredb

In a basic EventStore three-node cluster with no node-priority, after terminating two nodes, the remaining node continuously attempts to elect itself but never successfully assumes the **master** role.

Clients (specifically C# / .NET clients, as tested) can connect to the node (utilizing cluster configuration), yet both subscribing to a persistent subscription and publishing to a stream are unsuccessful.

Furthermore, the web interface for this node generates an exception when trying to access the persistent subscriptions. In the cluster tab, the node displays the status as "**unknown**."

Here is an example of `EventStore.ClusterNode` arguments for one node:

```
--int-ip 127.0.0.1 --ext-ip 127.0.0.1 --int-tcp-port=1111 --ext-tcp-port=1112 --int-http-port=1113 --ext-http-port=1114 --cluster-size=3 --discover-via-dns=false --gossip-seed=127.0.0.1:2113,127.0.0.1:3113
```

Is this behavior intentional, or might there be a missing element in the configuration?

Comment: I believe this is by design. If you claim a 3 node cluster in the config, then you need at least 2 nodes to form a quorum.

Comment: That makes somehow sense, considering the single node doesn't know if he can't reach the other two nodes. The behauviour is the same in a two node cluster, which seems wierd for me, because that would require a minimun of 3 nodes for clustering, which is not mentioned in the docs and it doesn't allow a basic two node failover. Is there really no configuration that would enforce a node to become **master** once that node is the only one in the cluster (from his own perspective of course)?

Comment: in the case of a network partition, where the 3 nodes split into a 2 and a 1, in your situation, the 2 node cluster would elect a master and the 1 node cluster would elect a master and all clients would think they were connected to a master, but actually they would be connected to two different, forked  versions of the same cluster. which would result in a situation which I think would be unrecoverable

Comment: I perfectly understand the idea of a quorum, however our nodes are physically near each other, connected to the same internal network and as such a network split is less probable than a zombie apocalypse. That's why I would like to configure the cluster to be able to elect a master, if that one belives to be the last one alive. Also wondering why the [docs](https://eventstore.org/docs/server/cluster-with-manager-nodes/index.html) only recommend an uneven number of nodes instead of mentioning that this is required.